# redux react and socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux, react-redux

I somehow managed to get it work, but i think it is not good solution.

my main file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router,  hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import routes from './router/routes';
import store from './store.js';

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={ store }>
    <Router routes={ routes } history={ hashHistory } />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('wrap')
);
```

my store.js is:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers/index';
import initialState from './reducers/initial-state';
import connection from './lib/connection';

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

connection(store);

export default store;
```

and connection is:

```
import AppActions from '../actions/AppActions';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default function (store) {

const mainsocket = io.connect('$socketurl');

mainsocket.store = store;
mainsocket.actions = AppActions;

var socket;

mainsocket.on('namespaceinitialized', function(data) {

socket = io.connect("$socketurl/$namespace", {'autoConnect': false,'forceNew': true});
socket.connect();

socket.store = store;
socket.actions = AppActions;


socket.on('connect',function (data) {

//need store and actions

});

});

}
```

As you see i am using 2 connections, first for namespace initialize and then second (this is not important in question).

I dont like this "dirty" solution where i am attaching store and actions to mainsocket object and then passing them from mainsocket to socket, in order to have access to app actions on socket messages, and the question is what is right way?

Also in this code socket connects before app actions and store have initialized, i would like to socket connection be last thing but i don't know where to put it then?

I must say that i am don't writing my own application but adding functionality to existing open source one.

thank you.

Comment: how can your socket connect before your store initializes? it definitely looks to me that you are calling `createStore` before `io.connect`. right?

Comment: Also.. I think your question is a little too broad for an answer. Maybe you don't like the approach, but to write a better one we need to know where your approach is falling short, or what you perceive to be an improvement. There are dozens if not hundreds of ways to wire up socket.io with react / redux

Comment: I would just want a better way to access store and action in second socket callback, and how to make to socket connect after application initializes

Comment: well React applications have `componentDidMount` which is a sign that the application has initialized. You can not call `connect `until that event happens. `store` can be accessed in a number of ways.. by exposing it as a module or by using `react-redux`'s `connect` function